# Why is my Flutter app not working on iOS emulator with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, emulation

My Flutter app compiles and runs on emulators (iOS and Android) via Android Studio. It does run on real devices (via Android Studio and Xcode) but not on emulator via Xcode. The app locks on loading screen.

Can someone tell me why ? This implies that I am not able to send a working build on the Apple App Store.

This is the error I get :

```
2019-10-06 23:22:10.949096+0200 Runner[58237:200800] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named 
com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The 
connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

1) Run in terminal

```
   xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off"  --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

2) From Xcode menu go to `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme` 
Locate where Environment Variables is and set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`

3) Restart simulator

PS. If you have an error message `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH` 
then please go to `Xcode > Preferences > Locations` and Assign the Command Line Tools